# ImageResizer not working on <img> Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am using ImageResizer from [ImageResizing.net](http://imageresizing.net/).

Through my code, I am able to programatically use the plugin using this code:

```
img.Attributes.Add("src", RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrl("http://i.minus.com/iNQ7wK2opRJT1.gif",
                                                                             new ResizeSettings(
                                                                                 "width=233&format=png")));
```

But, When I try to directly use the Plugin with the `<img />` tag, such as:

`<img id="img" alt="" src="http://i.minus.com/iNQ7wK2opRJT1.gif?width=90" />`

It simply renders the full size image. Through both methods, I'm just adding the `src` to the image, followed with the query string.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:** I am using skins, but they aren't messing with `<img />` at all.
**Edit 2:** I have the [RemoteReader Plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/remotereader)

Comment: Are you trying to use syntax #1 or #2? It looks like you may be missing something. From #1 a .ashx extension, or from #2 a subfolder in the path

Comment: Another question, if you try to use the resizer on local files, does it work ok? What's the output of /resizer.debug.ashx look like?

Comment: Local images worked. I used a `WebService` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageResizer can only process HTTP requests it receives; it does NOT magically modify your HTML for you. URLs that point to a different server... go to that server.

The RemoteReader plugin offers an alternate human-writeable syntax, but you must whitelist the domain as specified in the [RemoteReader documentation](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/remotereader).

Example:

```
<img id="img" alt="" src="/remote/i.minus.com/iNQ7wK2opRJT1.gif?width=90" />
```